# Selecting AWS storage services for storing user data

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds

I am a computer science undergraduate student. I am working on the activity recognition Android Application. My application reads the data from the mobile sensor (Acc+Gyro+Mag) and then does some basic processing in the mobile itself. Now, I am trying to upload this data to the AWS.
Let me explain this project in detail. I have developed an application which can tell about the user activity by reading the data from the mobile sensor and it stores data locally on the mobile. Now, I am trying to gather more data from the different set of users, therefore, I need to upload this data to the cloud. I have little bit knowledge of AWS but not an expert. I am using mobile hub services of the AWS, in this module, I have found DynmoDB but somewhere I studied it is only good for storing data less than 2MB.
I have also found many storage services on the AWS such as DynmoDB, RedShift, and RDS. Now, I am getting confused. Which Service do I need to use?

One Line Problem: I want to store sensor reading on the cloud in real-time as well as at one time (after gathering some data). Which services do I need to use?

P.S. I have tried to explain my project and problem both. If you want more info please let me know

Comment: Depends on your requirements like cost, durability, scalability, performance, size of data, type of queries etc With RDS, AWS manages the administration and maintenance. Redshift is typically used as a Data Warehouse

Comment: Do you mean each sample or record is greater than 2MB? Also, what do you want to do with the data? Do you need to run SQL on it? Or read it into a program and process it? Will you read a given record once or many times?

Answer (score 1):

Where are you seeing that DynamoDB is only good for less than 2MB of data? DynamoDB has a limit of 400KB per item, but there is no limit on the size of the table. Will each record/item you upload to AWS be larger than 400KB?

DynamoDB seems like a perfect solution for this sort of thing. This is the type of application that is commonly referred to in DynamoDB tutorials and examples. If storing the data in a NoSQL database works for you, then I would recommend DynamoDB.

If you need to store the data in a relational format then you would need to look at RDS databases or possibly Redshift, depending on the type of queries you plan to do.

If each piece of data is very large, then you might need to upload it from your mobile application to S3 and then process it in AWS according to your needs.

Comment: I want to perform some operations on the data gathered from various users. In that aspect which storage service is suitable for us?

Comment: You aren't providing enough information for a concrete recommendation. What sort of operations do you need to perform? How much total data will there be? How large will each record be?

Comment: I'm saving data in SQlite database in the form of tables on an android device. Now i want to upload this data on cloud storage on real time basis.  In this aspect i want some advice on which AWS storage database to use?

Comment: You haven't answered any of my questions, and you just added a "real time" requirement. I'm sorry but I'm not going to be able to provide more detailed answers.